# Find Ninject Bindings by Implementation Type

Tags: .net, ninject

How do I get a list of bindings which are bound to a particular implementation type?

```
IKernel.Bind<IService>().To(implementationType);
```

something like this ?

```
var bindings = IKernel.GetBindings(typeof(IService))
                  .Where(b=>b.ImplementationType==implementationType)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not easily. If you can somehow construct a Ninject Context, you can do

```
Kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IService))
     .Where(b => b.GetProvider(context).Type == implementationType)
```

**UPDATE**

Actually there is an alternate way to do it. When declaring your bindings you can supply metadata

```
Kernel.Bind<IService>().To(implementationType)
     .WithMetadata("type", implementationType);
```

Then you can get all bindings by doing this

```
Kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IService))
     .Where(b => b.Metadata.Get<Type>("type") == implementationType)
```